# Connect Excel to local Power BI desktop data model

Tags: excel, powerbi

Scenario:

- I use Power BI desktop to develop a Power BI app with datamodel and reports
- The app is published to Power BI service
- End users use the app in two ways:

  - They use the published reports
  - They connect to the published PowerBI dataset from Excel (to analyze and visualize in Excel)

Questions/issues:

- I would like to test the "connect-to-powerbi-dataset-from-excel"-scenario without publishing to the Power BI service
- Is there a way to connect to my local PowerBI desktop data model from Excel?